mlogit in R -- successfully coercing categorical variable
I'm trying to expand a replication dataset to estimate the multinomial logit model of a categorical outcome. But the mlogit.data function is coercing my categorical outcome variable with values of 0, 1, and 2 to a true/false binary, which I think is screwing up my modeling.
When I run summary(data_filtered), my baseline dataframe, I can still see the full range of values for M_RUF, my primary outcome variable.
X              M_RUF             RUF2             CDF         MUD           EDUCATION
Min.   :   2.0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000
1st Qu.: 197.8   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000
Median : 570.5   Median :1.0000   Median :1.0000   Median :0   Median :1.0000   Median :1.0000
Mean   : 536.0   Mean   :0.7591   Mean   :0.6757   Mean   :0   Mean   :0.6304   Mean   :0.8098
3rd Qu.: 821.0   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:2.0000
Max.   :1227.0   Max.   :2.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :0   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :2.0000
SLPP           Mende          NOPARTY       EXC_SURV_LOC         id
Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.000   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :    1.0
1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:27.75   1st Qu.:  141.8
Median :0.000   Median :1.000   Median :1.000   Median :42.00   Median : 4007.5
Mean   :0.212   Mean   :0.538   Mean   :0.529   Mean   :41.06   Mean   : 4873.6
3rd Qu.:0.000   3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:56.00   3rd Qu.: 8036.2
Max.   :1.000   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :66.00   Max.   :14086.0
But that gets screwy once I introduce the mlogit.data function, coercing my M_RUF variable into a logical binary.
data_long <- mlogit.data(data_filtered, shape = "wide", choice = "M_RUF", id.var = "id")
summary(data_long)

   X            M_RUF              RUF2             CDF         MUD           EDUCATION     

Min.   :   2.0   Mode :logical   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000
1st Qu.: 197.8   FALSE:1104      1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000
Median : 570.5   TRUE :552       Median :1.0000   Median :0   Median :1.0000   Median :1.0000
Mean   : 536.0                   Mean   :0.6757   Mean   :0   Mean   :0.6304   Mean   :0.8098
3rd Qu.: 821.0                   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:2.0000
Max.   :1227.0                   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :0   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :2.0000
SLPP           Mende          NOPARTY       EXC_SURV_LOC         id
Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.000   Min.   :0.000   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :    1.0
1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:0.000   1st Qu.:27.75   1st Qu.:  141.8
Median :0.000   Median :1.000   Median :1.000   Median :42.00   Median : 4007.5
Mean   :0.212   Mean   :0.538   Mean   :0.529   Mean   :41.06   Mean   : 4873.6
3rd Qu.:0.000   3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:1.000   3rd Qu.:56.00   3rd Qu.: 8036.2
Max.   :1.000   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :66.00   Max.   :14086.0
chid        alt          idx.chid              idx.alt
Min.   :   2.0   0:552   Min.   :   2.0000    0:552
1st Qu.: 191.8   1:552   1st Qu.: 191.7500    1:552
Median : 542.5   2:552   Median : 542.5000    2:552
Mean   : 503.7           Mean   : 503.6975    NA
3rd Qu.: 770.0           3rd Qu.: 770.0000    NA
Max.   :1103.0           Max.   :1103.0000    NA
When I try to run my model, I get a correlation error, which doesn't make sense given the variation I observe in my pre-mlogit.data dataframe.
mlogit_model <- mlogit(M_RUF ~ MUD + EDUCATION + SLPP + Mende + NOPARTY | 0, data = data_long)

Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) :
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
